# MS Access query on two crosstab queries for a multiple value query

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot, crosstab

I am trying to build a query on two crosstab queries for a multiple value query in MS Access 2010. I have read the support article on this but I do not understand how to write an actual query from the schema it offers. And I did not find any actual queries through the Internet search that would address my problem.

I have 2 crosstab queries. 1st gives me total hours for each category/project pivoted by the field "Type" (which has values e, n, or t). The 2nd gives me total cost for each category/project pivoted by the field "Type" (which has values e, n, or t).
I need to put the two together so I would have Hours and Cost for each Type of each Project/Category as follows:

```
                             Hours      Cost        
Category    Project Name    e   n   t   e       n       t
Category 1  Project 1       5   6       $500    $687    
Category 1  Project 2       12  34  48  $5,843  $9,987  $15,800 
Category 2  Project 1       19  2       $2457   $88
Category 2  Project 3       21      35  $18122          $1200
```

From what I understood from various sources, I created the following query:

SELECT [Cost by Project Category Crosstab Query (Hours)].Category, [Cost by Project Category Crosstab Query (Hours)].[Project Name], [Cost by Project Category Crosstab Query (Hours)].Hours, [Cost by Project Category Crosstab Query (Cost)].Cost
FROM [Cost by Project Category Crosstab Query (Hours)] INNER JOIN [Cost by Project Category Crosstab Query (Cost)] ON ([Cost by Project Category Crosstab Query (Hours)].[Category]=[Cost by Project Category Crosstab Query (Cost)].[Category]) AND ([Cost by Project Category Crosstab Query (Hours)].[Project Name]=[Cost by Project Category Crosstab Query (Cost)].[Project Name])
GROUP BY [Cost by Project Category Crosstab Query (Hours)].Category, [Cost by Project Category Crosstab Query (Hours)].[Project Name];

It runs and asks for parameters. After getting them, the query gives me an error that Access does not recognize " as a valid field name or expression. I must be doing something wrong because all the names seem to be correct.

How can I achieve the result I want? Thanks.

P.S. I do not worry about actual headings, like Hours and Cost. I used them to explain the numbers.